# Highcharts Gauge

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm using highcharts and i'd like to show a big gauge(500x500px).
Resizing the gauge was quite easy, but the small block with the value in it doesn't resize. How can I make that small block bigger?

Thanks for the help!

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AVd8k/

```
$(function () {

$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false,
        width: 500,
        height: 500
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Speedometer'
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: -150,
        endAngle: 150,
        background: [{
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#FFF'],
                    [1, '#333']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '109%'
        }, {
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#333'],
                    [1, '#FFF']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 1,
            outerRadius: '107%'
        }, {
            // default background
        }, {
            backgroundColor: '#DDD',
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '105%',
            innerRadius: '103%'
        }]
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200,

        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        minorTickWidth: 1,
        minorTickLength: 10,
        minorTickPosition: 'inside',
        minorTickColor: '#666',

        tickPixelInterval: 30,
        tickWidth: 2,
        tickPosition: 'inside',
        tickLength: 10,
        tickColor: '#666',
        labels: {
            step: 2,
            rotation: 'auto'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'km/h'
        },
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 120,
            color: '#55BF3B' // green
        }, {
            from: 120,
            to: 160,
            color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
        }, {
            from: 160,
            to: 200,
            color: '#DF5353' // red
        }]        
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]

}, 
// Add some life
function (chart) {
    if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
        setInterval(function () {
            var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                newVal,
                inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

            newVal = point.y + inc;
            if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
                newVal = point.y - inc;
            }

            point.update(newVal);

        }, 3000);
    }
});
});
```

[image: Highcharts Gauge]

Comment: What code or adjustements you did ? Show us

Comment: I've added the code and a link to jsFiddle.

Comment: See my answer on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this by replacing `series` (whole object) with:

```
series: [{
            name: 'Speed',
            data: [80],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' km/h'
            },
            dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        //fontWeight:'bold',
                        fontSize: '22px'
                    }
                }
        }]
```

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/nmQfE/

Of course, you can adjust the font size as you want

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the property you are after is:
plotOptions.gauge.dataLabels.style.fontSize

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.gauge.dataLabels.style

Try adding something like this to the options:

```
plotOptions: {
    gauge: {
        dataLabels: { 
            style: {
                fontSize: '60px'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may need to reposition it using the x and y properties.